# How to embed the trimesh show in a python GTK3 app?

Tags: python, gtk3, trimesh

I need to make a GTK3 application in Python that includes a mesh visualized with Trimesh.

```py
mesh = trimesh.load(filename)
mesh.is_watertight
mesh.euler_number
np.divide(mesh.volume, mesh.convex_hull.volume)
mesh.vertices -= mesh.center_mass
mesh.moment_inertia
mesh.split()
try:
  for facet in mesh.facets:
    mesh.visual.face_colors[facet] = trimesh.visual.random_color()
except ValueError:
  pass

# preview mesh in an opengl window if you installed pyglet with pip
mesh.show()
```

This opens a new window. I would like instead of opening a new window to be displayed in an area of the GTK app.
Thanks in advance.